# How can i detect the URL change in window iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I've Create an iframe window on load of component,

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (iframeurl?.length) {
      const windowOptions = "width=400,height=400";
      const myWindow = window.open(iframeurl, "New Window", windowOptions);
      myWindow?.focus();
      setIframeWindow(myWindow);
    }
  }, [iframeurl]);
```

Now I want to watch the URL change in that window, is it possible to detect that changes?
I've tried one solution but it's not working

```
if(iframeWindow){
    try {
      iframeWindow.addEventListener("load", (e:any) => {
        console.log(iframeWindow.location.href);
        console.log('event', e);
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error ====>>>>", error);
    }
  }
```

Basically, I'm trying to open the Iframe window on component load, in this iframe I'm loading the 3rd party login url, then after the user successfully logins to that iframe, the I frame closes.

I can open the iframe window, but what I want to do is close it based on url change, since if the person successfully logs in, it will redirect to another url.

Comment: A login to/via a 3rd-party service should never happen inside an iframe to begin with - users will have no way to determine that they will actually be submitting this data to that 3rd-party service, and not somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Okay just want to tell you that if you have iframe url with different origin you wont be able to add any listener to it. Browser dont allow it.

If the iframe is something your own second app, add close logic in it. If its a third party, i guess then there must exposed method to close it in finish, some redirect URI or something.

Comment: I have add this Event listener but i can not get the event log, is there any other way?

Comment: I have updated the questions to make them easier to grasp.

Comment: i have updated the answer, can you try that once

Comment: @Smitlathiya do you want to open a new window or on same window?

Comment: I want to open in new window

Comment: Okay just want to tell you that if you have iframe url with different origin you wont be able to add any listener to it. Browser dont allow it.

Comment: Oh, Thank you for you Guidance.